# What happens when you kill the Samsung Kies Wifi Agent?

Tags: samsung-kies, macos

My Macbook Pro was [running hot, the fans running constantly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40460/fans-running-more-cant-see-why). This is not usual behavior. When I looked at the running processes, I saw that the Kies Wifi Agent was gobbling up a lot of RAM. I tried killing the process, and the temperature dropped by sixty-eight degrees.

I assume the agent will start up again the next time I reboot. My question: Aside from not being able to use wifi from the Mac to the tablet, what will this do? Can I permanently kill the agent, or is there some way to set it to only run when I need it?

I'm running Mac OSX 10.6.8, and using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 plus wifi.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple to turn this off. I'm using OSX 10.7.4 and I did this:

I went to "System Preferences", then in the line "System" I went to "Users and Groups". At the top, there is "Password" and something like "Login Items". I went to this "Login Items" and just clicked one time in "KiesViaWifiAgent" and then in the " - " button under it.

Now, I can reboot the MacBook Pro and it will not start up by itself.

Comment: Thanks, and your English is fine. I've since figured this out on my own, but this answer prompted me to take a look, and there's also a startup item named [fuspreddownloader](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3286521?start=0&tstart=0), which also seems to be a Samsung component. Have just unchecked that as well. But this doesn't answer an important aspect of the question: Is there any other effect on the Mac to turning these off? (I did it a few months ago and haven't noticed any problems.)